# c++ bad alloc applicaition failure

Tags: c++, bad-alloc

I have a piece of code where I dynamically create some relatively big objects (14MB) and populate a vector with them (of size 260). I am getting a bad alloc exception which I am catching. The application is still usable after my first throw, then when I relaunch it the bad alloc exception is thrown once again but the application is not usable anymore.
Do you know if there is a way to keep it usable even after the exception is thrown (no matter the number of times it is thrown).

Thanks

Comment: It would be best to share some (relevant) code for us to have a chance to help

Comment: Sorry i meant MB (i edited my question)

Comment: For the 2nd exception, there must be some extra information which points out the reason why app must end (different from first)

Comment: I get the same bad alloc message, only it continues to run until it crashes

Answer (score 1):

Now then array of 260 of 14Mb objects would require about 4Gb of RAM. And the tricky part is that it must be a solid block. So it could be not available due to memory fragmentation even if amount of free RAM is sufficient. You should try using non-contiguous container, such as `std::list` instead or `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<obj_t>>`. Application is usable regardless of amount of times exceptions are thrown (assuming that they are caught). And with greater granularity of allocations it should be less likely to fail to allocate memory.

Comment: I understand this, which is why I had the try catch(bad alloc). The issue is that when the exception is throw I expect everything to return to the state before the bad_alloc happens. Which is not the case since I can't relaunch the application a second time.

Comment: *"I can't relaunch the application a second time"* - what is preventing you from doing this?

Comment: When I relaunch it a second time I get the the error message but there is something still running (the application doesn't stop) then crashes.

Comment: @LightJecht You should investigate the crash then... Your question actually turns out to be an XY problem.

Comment: @LightJecht related:  https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/